# How to add rows into dataframe when columns are not the same?

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, I have the original dataframe with the four column, called 'old_data':

```
name type age location
```

Then I need to add some new rows into this dataframe, but it only has two columns:

```
name age
```

The new data to be added is a list of dicts, called 'new_data':

```
[{name:age}, {name:age}, {name:age}]
```

How to do this when columns are not matched?

Comment: Have you considered creating a new dataframe for this list of dictionaries and then performing a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# original data-frame
df = pd.DataFrame([{"name":"john", "type":"", "age":"12", "location":"so"},
                   {"name":"jane", "type":"", "age":"12", "location":"so"}])

# convert existing dict to array of dict's
data = {"james":"20", "rich":"30"}
new_df = pd.DataFrame([{"name":k, "age":v} for k, v in data.items()])

# use data-frame append to add to existing df, missing values will be filled with NaN
df = df.append(new_df, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Output

```
  age location   name type
0  12       so   john     
1  12       so   jane     
2  20      NaN  james  NaN
3  30      NaN   rich  NaN
```